# I cannot create a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I tried creating a list workflow in SharePoint 2010.

When I click New Workflow, I could see `Add new workflow to your list` and I have entered the workflow name and clicked OK. It remains in the same page without creating a workflow and I have seen in one website saying SharePoint Designer 2010 should be not be 15.0 version. If so, we need to install SharePoint Designer 2013. And also let me know whether its possible to create a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 for SharePoint 2010 list?

Comment: For 2010 you should only use 2010 SharePoint Designer. I believe you might have read it wrongly. Can you try closing the designer and starting again? Also make sure you have enough permissions on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried closing the designer and started again. But its still the same. And I have full control (Owner access) to the site.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Install SharePoint Designer 2013. Then do the following steps:

1. Delete all folders in the following directory on your computer:
   C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache\
2. Delete the files in all folders in this directory on your computer:
   C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\  (don’t delete the folders, delete the contents of the folders)

Sources:

http://knowsharepoint.com/problems-creating-list-workflows-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-for-office-365-sites/

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/85904

Comment: The source is referring to office 365 but the question was asking about SP2010. Anyway, the question was 6 years ago... why it is being raised to top?